# Python regex splitting a paragraph into sentences where each sentence starts with a name

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to split a paragraph of sentences into sub-strings, where the paragraph is split at the end of every sentence. Each new sentence begins with a player's name. My main issue is accommodating for all of the potential formats for the player name at the beginning of each sentence. Here are some examples:

INPUT:

```
Kentucky 1st - T. Pompey grounded out to 2b (2-0 BB). E. White lined out to cf (1-0 B). Z. Reks homered to right field, RBI (3-2 BFBBK). K. Cottam struck out swinging (1-2 KKBS). 

UT Martin 2nd - KERWIN struck out looking (1-2 KSBK). ELDRIDGE fouled out to 3b (1-0 B). WESSLING walked (3-2 BKKBBK). STEEN reached on an error by ss (0-0); WESSLING advanced to second.

Belmont 2nd - EGLI, N. grounded out to 3b (0-1 K). BOURNIGAL, R walked (3-2 BSKBBB). KOCHER, B. walked (3-1 FBBBB); BOURNIGAL, R advanced to second. KOCHER, B. advanced to second; BOURNIGAL, R advanced to third on a throwing error by p.

Murray State 3rd - Bence, A. singled to left field (2-0 BB). Bence, A. stole second. Bauer, A. flied out to lf to left center (2-1 FBB); Bence, A. advanced to third. Gutzler, B. flied out to lf, SAC, RBI (1-0 B); Bence, A. scored. Hranec, J. fouled out to 1b (0-0).
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
'Kentucky 1st - '
'T. Pompey grounded out to 2b (2-0 BB).'
'E. White lined out to cf (1-0 B).'
'Z. Reks homered to right field, RBI (3-2 BFBBK).'
'K. Cottam struck out swinging (1-2 KKBS).'

'UT Martin 2nd - '
'KERWIN struck out looking (1-2 KSBK).'
'ELDRIDGE fouled out to 3b (1-0 B).'
'WESSLING walked (3-2 BKKBBK).'
'STEEN reached on an error by ss (0-0); WESSLING advanced to second.'

'Belmont 2nd - '
'EGLI, N. grounded out to 3b (0-1 K).'
'BOURNIGAL, R walked (3-2 BSKBBB).'
'KOCHER, B. walked (3-1 FBBBB); BOURNIGAL, R advanced to second.'
'KOCHER, B. advanced to second; BOURNIGAL, R advanced to third on a throwing error by p.'

'Murray State 3rd - '
'Bence, A. singled to left field (2-0 BB).'
'Bence, A. stole second.'
'Bauer, A. flied out to lf to left center (2-1 FBB); Bence, A. advanced to third.'
'Gutzler, B. flied out to lf, SAC, RBI (1-0 B); Bence, A. scored.'
'Hranec, J. fouled out to 1b (0-0).'
```

My attempt at a code to provide the following outputs is as follows (note 'team' in the following code would just refer to the team that starts the paragraph - e.g. Kentucky, UT Martin or Belmont:

```
s = re.split(r'[.][ ](?=[A-Z][^.])|[.][ ](?=[0-9])', s)
for i, x in enumerate(s):
     x = x.split('.')[0]
     if ' - ' in x:
          team = '\n' + re.split(r'[0-9]', x.split(' - ')[0])[0].replace(';','').strip()
          print(team + '\n')
          y = x.split(' - ')[1] + '.'
          if len(y)>2:
               print(y + '\n')
          else:
               x = x + '.'
               print(x + '\n')
```

Comment: How about matching everything up to the first occurrence of dash?

Comment: I still need to split the sentences when a player name occurs after a '.', where first initials are giving me some trouble.

Comment: Please update the test cases in the question. `Sims, D. struck out swinging (1-2 KSBS). Perkins, R. reached on an error by 1b (2-2 KBBSF).` is not at all similar to the samples you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you formulate the pattern differently then you likely won't have to do any enumeration:

```
s = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[^-] -|[A-Z][.][ ][^.]+|[A-Z]+[,.]*[ ]*[A-Z]*[,.]*[ ][^.]+)|.', s)
s = filter(None, s)

for v in s:
    print(v.strip('\n\n'))
```

**Result**:

```
Kentucky 1st -
T. Pompey grounded out to 2b (2-0 BB)
E. White lined out to cf (1-0 B)
Z. Reks homered to right field, RBI (3-2 BFBBK)
K. Cottam struck out swinging (1-2 KKBS)

UT Martin 2nd -
KERWIN struck out looking (1-2 KSBK)
ELDRIDGE fouled out to 3b (1-0 B)
WESSLING walked (3-2 BKKBBK)
STEEN reached on an error by ss (0-0); WESSLING advanced to second

Belmont 2nd -
EGLI, N. grounded out to 3b (0-1 K)
BOURNIGAL, R walked (3-2 BSKBBB)
KOCHER, B. walked (3-1 FBBBB); BOURNIGAL, R advanced to second
KOCHER, B. advanced to second; BOURNIGAL, R advanced to third on a throwing error by p
```

**Example**:

https://repl.it/JaIW/1

Comment: Awesome! That works like a charm for the examples I posted. I have one more example that I forget to include, but I don't think it should be too difficult to add (i.e. Sims, D. struck out swinging (1-2 KSBS). Perkins, R. reached on an error by 1b (2-2 KBBSF).)

Comment: Always include every possible example, regardless adding those two should work fine with the pattern unless it falls after the `;` ...

Comment: Apologies for that :/  The issue with this last example is that the last name of the player is not all caps